# Dojo can't remove child element in IE 11

Tags: javascript, dojo, internet-explorer-11

I have java web application with front end in Dojo. There is workflow consisting of several pages one after another but user can go back and forth.

Now, for Chrome, Firefox etc., it works flawlessly, but for IE 11, if user goes back from one specific page to previous and then forward again to that specific page, navigation doesn't work.

What hapepns here is that error is thrown on

```
"tabContainer.removeChild( oldTab );"
```

saying:

```
Unable to get property 'removeChild' of undefined or null reference
```

and when I check in console it is that: tabContainer is not null, oldTab is not null (of course) but tabContainer.removeChild( oldTab ) doesn't work.

Now during first pass, when user comes for the first time to specific page, element `someObjectsPanel is <div></div>`
than that element someObjectsPanel become `<div style="visibility: hidden;"></div>`

I've tried to use: `dojo.style(someObjectsPanel, "visibility", "visible" )`
and even `UTIL.clearNode('someTabWidget');` but doesn't work.

After `var tabContainer = new dijitc.layout.TabContainer( tabArgs, someObjectsPanel );`

someObjectsPanel become `<div style="visibility: hidden;"></div>` and it was `<div></div>`, I don't know it that could be the problem?

This is function where I get error:

```
fillSomeTab = function(policy) {
    UTIL.clearNode('someTabWidget'); //<---- tried with this, didn't help
    var somePanel = dijit.byId('someTabWidget').domNode;
    var someObjectsPanel = somePanel.appendChild( dojo.doc.createElement('div') );
    var tabArgs = { 'class':'richTab color someObjectsPanel', 'nested':true };
    var tabContainer = new dijitc.layout.TabContainer( tabArgs, someObjectsPanel );
    tabContainer.startup();

    var tab = new dijit.layout.ContentPane( {"title":g_someBean.someObjects[0].car.brandText+' '+g_someBean.someObjects[0].car.modelText, "class":"stepBarPanel someObjectTab"}, dojo.doc.createElement('div'));
    tabContainer.addChild(tab);
    var dataAnchor = dojo.create( "div", {"class":"someData autosomeData"}, tab.domNode );

    var oldTab = dijit.byId('someoneTabContainer');
    if( oldTab != null ) {
        tabContainer.removeChild( oldTab ); //<--- it breaks here, 
        oldTab.destroyRecursive();
    }
```

Comment: Any chance to narrow your case to make it runnable on jsfiddle.net? That would encourage more people to take a closer look :) And BTW I have never heard of `dijitc`, is it a typo or some forked version of `dijit`?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Unfortunately, I removed the elements children manually one by one. 
It seems IE 11 does not support that.